# shell: iterate over array

Tags: bash

My script accepts key-value pairs as command line arguments. I test if the given number of arguments are even or not. If even, I want to iterate over array, consider `args[n]` & `args[n+1]` as a pair `(n = 0 to $# - 1)` and execute another command that will take these two as arguments. I am unable to get the for loop in place. Here's my code -

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
    echo "$0 <property-name> <property-value> [<property-name> <property-value> ...]"
    exit 1
}

if [ $# -lt 2 ] ; then
    usage
fi

# Should be even number of arguments
if [ $(( $# % 2 )) -ne 0 ]
    echo "Even number of arguments expected."
    usage
fi
args=("$@")
COMMAND="/mycommand "
for ### WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE??
    PROPERTY=${args[$c]}
    VALUE=${args[$c + 1]}
    COMMAND="mycommand $PROPERTY $VALUE"
    ## Execute command
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
for ((i=0; i<${#args[@]}; i+=2)); do
    PROPERTY="${args[$i]}"
    VALUE="${args[$i + 1]}"
    COMMAND="mycommand $PROPERTY $VALUE"
    bash -c "$COMMAND"
done
```

I recommend to not using CAPITALISED characters as variable name, keep those for your internal system variables

Comment: Shouldn't the for loop iterate n/2 times, at least in the first case. I am still trying to understand 2nd piece.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will change my script accordingly.

Comment: The `i+2` in the first line should be `i=i+2`

Answer (score 3):

First note, this looks awkward

```
if [ $(( $# % 2 )) -ne 0 ]
```

Use a single arithmetic expression instead:

```
if (( ($# % 2) != 0 ))
```

It's not necessary to use an array for the args:

```
command="/mycommand"
while (( $# > 0 )); do
    property=$1
    value=$2
    shift 2
    ## Execute command
    "$command" "$property" "$value"
done
```

The quoting is pretty crucial in case any of the properties or values contain whitespace

I assume you intend to execute the command with just a single property and value in each iteration of the loop. If not, you can simple do:

```
"$command" "$@"
```